# Symfony2 with Bootstrap3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony

i just intalled symfony2 to build a website and i didn't got problems with bootstrap3 because i did use it separatly but i integrated it in Symfony2. since i  have a lot of problem i can't use some classes like glyphicons, dropdown menus or modal.[image] 
so please tell me how i can set it up so that it works.

please see the picture below i got a lot of folders

i enabled bootstrap 3

```html
{% block stylesheets %}
 {% stylesheets filter='cssrewrite' 
   '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
   '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
   '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'
   '%kernel.root_dir%/../vendor/twbs/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css'
   '@pageshomeBundle/Resources/css/*'
  %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}">
  {% endstylesheets %}
{% endblock %}
```

so why is it different than the free version that i downloaded?
thanks for your answers in advance

Comment: You are duplicating the css files. You should either use `bootstrap.css` or `bootstrap.min.css`. The same applies for the `bootstra-theme.css`.

Answer (score 0):

What is seams from your picture that bootstrap directory is not publicly accessible folder via HTTP protocol, so when CSS url declaration requests for file, it can not access it.

I haven't seen this practice that you are using in projects, usually, people use Components for SF project, and they set the components directory to be "web/components".

See this project: https://github.com/RobLoach/component-installer

This will allow you to use some of the popular libraries via Composer. I honestly recommend it.